# Extending a remote GraphQL Schema

Tags: graphql

We have a remote schema such that we have a root field called `Persons`. The root field returns all the `Person` in the remote database. This field doesn't take an argument like `Persons(id: "123")`.

I am importing this remote schema into my server but I want to extend it to add the required `Persons(id: "123")` to return one person.

I know all about renaming types, renaming root fields and things like that. But I am not sure if it is possible to extend the remote schema. If yes, how can this be achieved?

I am particularly looking to do this is Javascript, but help in any platform will be appreciated.